# What is the role of NaHSO3 in syn diol formation from alkenes with OsO4?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

All I have found on this is that NaHSO<sub>3</sub> reduces partially the osmate ester, so breaks off Os and leaves a syn diol. Is it possible to show this step with arrows showing the process of electron movement? I suppose this step is not the main part of the reaction, and mayn't be very important, but I would like to know if it's possible - and if it is, how it looks.

Answer (score 7):

After you add the $\ce{OsO_4}$ to make the reaction, you'll need to reduce the remaining $\ce{OsO_4}$ maintaining the $\ce{pH}$ of the solution constant.

In addition:

> The hydrolysis of the osmate ester proceeds by simple substitution
>   reactions. The $\ce{NaHSO3}$, a mild reducing agent, facilitates ligand
>   subsitution by reducing the $\ce{Os}$ further.

The Art of Writing Reasonable Organic Reaction Mechanisms, Robert B. Grossman, p 293

And $\ce{NaHSO_3}$ can do both and so you will use it. You also can add $\ce{Na_2SO_3}$.

---

I found also something interesting on [JACS](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr00032a009), it's mentioned at least four times in the document that $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is used as buffer. Also there is a lot of information in the references of this article.

> While the reaction is normally run under basic conditions
>   ($\ce{K_2CO_3}$, $\ce{pH} = 12.2$, aqueous layer), it is possible to
>   buffer the system with $3$ equiv of $\ce{NaHCO3}$ ($\ce{pH} = 10.3$,
>   aqueous layer).$^{38, 39}$ Buffering of the reaction mixture does not
>   affect the ee, but it can have a beneficial effect on the yield when
>   base-sensitive substrates are used or base-sensitive products are
>   formed. Thus, the AD of allyl or cinnamyl halides (cf. eqs $1$ and
>   $3$) should be performed under buffered conditions to minimize epoxide
>   formation (see eq $1$, the yield with allyl bromide as substrate is
>   between $61$ and $74%$ under buffered conditions; in the absence of
>   $\ce{NaHCO3}$ only $40-50$ % of diol is obtained38). Unfortunately,
>   the AD reaction does not turn over if $\ce{K_2CO_3}$ is replaced
>   entirely by $\ce{NaHCO3}$.

Hartmuth C. Kolb, Michael S. VanNieuwenhze, K. Barry Sharpless
Chem. Rev., 1994, 94 (8), p 2494